# Azure push notification not closing after click when app is open

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I am using azure push notification for my Xamarin forms app. Its working fine. But in Android when app is open, If I click my notification its not closing. If app is background its closing correctly.

MainActivity

```
    protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
{ 
     base.OnNewIntent(intent);
     ProcessNotificationActions(intent);
     CreateNotificationFromIntent(intent);
     LoadApplication(new App PushNotificationFirebaseMessagingService.PushNotificationPageName, PushNotificationFirebaseMessagingService.PushNotificationAppName, PushNotificationFirebaseMessagingService.Notification));
}
```

This is Dependency service for notitification

```
   public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        base.OnMessageReceived(message); 
        var msgData = message.Data; 
        var NotificationMessage = msgData["action"];

        var NotificationObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NotificationData>(NotificationMessage);
        ShowNotification(message.GetNotification().Body, message.GetNotification().Title, NotificationObj.Notification[0].OpenPage.ToString(), NotificationObj.AppName.ToString(), NotificationMessage);

    }
```

Show Notification Method

```
        public int ShowNotification(string message, string title,  string pageName, string appName,string NotificationMessage)
    {
        if (!channelInitialized)
        {
            CreateNotificationChannel();
        }

        _messageId++;  

        Intent intent = new Intent(AndroidApp.Context, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
        intent.PutExtra("title", title);
        intent.PutExtra("message", message);
        intent.PutExtra("OpenPage", pageName);
        intent.PutExtra("AppName", appName);
        intent.PutExtra("NotificationMessage", NotificationMessage); 

        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(mContext, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(AndroidApp.Context, ChannelId)
            .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .SetContentTitle(title)
            .SetContentText(message) 
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.addovation_icon)
            .SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.Sound | (int)NotificationDefaults.Vibrate);

        Notification notification = builder.Build();
        _manager.Notify(_messageId, notification);

        return _messageId;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notification only shows when the application is in **background or closed** .

When the application is running , the `OnMessageReceived` would be triggered but we can't see the notification.

The reason why the notification display is because you send **Local Notification** in `OnMessageReceived` method , to solve the problem , don't forget to dismiss it manually after clicking on it .

Refer to

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63037820/8187800.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have no idea how to dismiss it manually after click.

Comment: Could you share the code in method `ShowNotification` ?

Comment: I have added it my question. Please check

Comment: Change `NotificationManager ` flags, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/22218277/8187800 .